# I am unable to read data from xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have a onclick function in which there is a javascript function that runs to fetch data from xml. it is with jquery. but its not working. help plzzz.

**jsp page**

```
<script>

            function read() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "dictionary.xml",
                    datatype: "xml",
                    success: function data() {
                        $("ul").children().remove();
                        $(data).find("word").each(function () {
                            var info = '<li>Eng = ' + $(this).find("eng").text() + '</li><li>Beng = ' + $(this).find("beng").text() + '</li>';
                            $("ul").append(info);
                        });
                    }

                });
            }

        </script>
        <script src="WEB-INF/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="WEB-INF/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <ul></ul>


        <a href="#"  onclick="read();">Read</a>
```

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<corporate>
 <word>
   <eng>Male</eng>
   <beng>Man</beng>
 </word>
 <word>
   <eng>Female</eng>
   <beng>Woman</beng>
 </word> 
</corporate>
```

Comment: try replace `datatype` to `dataType`
and change    `success: function data() {` to `success: function (data) {`

Comment: changed buddy.. but no effect..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script src="WEB-INF/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="WEB-INF/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

remove any of these, as this will create two references to $ object.

put them into header or body tag, but before your script.

[working version](https://plnkr.co/edit/AWqH41KJOfgA8qhDTT0u)

```
 function read() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "test.xml",
                        datatype: "xml",
                        success: function (data) { //change it to function(data)
                          console.log(data);//check what is comming...
                            $("ul").children().remove();
                            $(data).find("word").each(function () {
                                var info = '<li>Eng = ' + $(data).find("eng").text() + '</li><li>Beng = ' + $(data).find("beng").text() + '</li>';
                                $("ul").append(info);
                            });
                        }

                    });
                }
```

Comment: thanxx,, but badluck.. still not getting the goal

Comment: what issue you are facing exactly ?

Comment: after clicking button i no data is displayed. and alert() is also not working when i tried to alert var info.

Comment: kindly check the link, i guess this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here you describe a function with no arguments, but with a local name:

```
success: function data() {
```

So, when you try to access `data`, you actually pass your function to jQuery, which does not make too much sense.

```
success: function data() {
    $(data).find("word").each(... // here, data is a function
```

`data` should be an argument:

```
success: function(data) {
    $(data).find("word").each(... // here, data is an XML object, passed to a handler
```

Comment: yes... correct.. i hv changed.. but still not getting data.

Comment: try to alert data in success function, and post the result you're getting

Comment: Also, bind logging function to ajax `error` property and see if there any errors from ajax request.